# CSS/JavaScript Use Div to grey out section of page

Tags: javascript, css

Does anybody know a way with JavaScript or CSS to basically grey out a certain part of a form/div in HTML?

I have a '*User Profile*' form where I want to disable part of it for a '*Non-Premium*' member, but want the user to see what is behind the form and place a '*Call to Action*' on top of it.

Does anybody know an easy way to do this either via CSS or JavaScript?

Edit: I will make sure that the form doesn't work on server side so CSS or JavaScript will suffice.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You might try the jQuery [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin.  It's quite flexible and is very easy to use, if you don't mind the dependency on jQuery.  It supports [element-level](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element) blocking as well an overlay message, which seems to be what you need.

The code to use it is as simple as:

```
$('div.profileform').block({
    message: '<h1>Premium Users only</h1>',
});
```

You should also keep in mind that you may still need some sort of server-side protection to make sure that Non-Premium users can't use your form, since it'll be easy for people to access the form elements if they use something like Firebug.

Comment: Excellent!! this is helpful to me

Answer (score 71):

Add this to your HTML:

```
<div id="darkLayer" class="darkClass" style="display:none"></div>
```

And this to your CSS:

```
.darkClass
{
    background-color: white;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    opacity: 0.5; /* Safari, Opera */
    -moz-opacity:0.50; /* FireFox */
    z-index: 20;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

And finally this to turn it off and on with JavaScript:

```
function dimOff()
{
    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display = "none";
}
function dimOn()
{
    document.getElementById("darkLayer").style.display = "";
}
```

Change the dimensions of the darkClass to suite your purposes.

Comment: change <div id="darkLayer" class="darkClass" display="none"></div>
 to 
<div id="darkLayer" class="darkClass" style="display:none"></div>

Comment: Don't forget to set `position: relative` on the parent of this darkClass component.

Comment: Can we also disable button controls inside such div.

Comment: This worked great. And if you are using JQuery anyway, you can do the following to turn on and off the layer: `function dimOff() { $('#darkLayer').css('display', "none"); }` and `function dimOn() { $('#darkLayer').css('display', ""); }`.

Comment: Works fantastic in Firefox but not in Chrome =(

Comment: In Chrome, the layer only covers the "above the fold" section of the screen - if you scroll down, or the browser auto-scrolls-down (it likes to remember the last place you were, before postback), everything below the fold is not covered by the div.

Answer (score 2):

If you rely on CSS or JavaScript to prevent a user from editing part of a form then this can easily by circumvented by disabling CSS or JavaScript.

A better solution might be to present the non-editable information outside of the form for non-premium members, but include the relevant form fields for premium members.

Comment: true, you could use php cookies for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
With opacity


//function to grey out the screen
$(function() {
// Create overlay and append to body:
$('<div id="ajax-busy"/>').css({
    opacity: 0.5, 
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: $(window).height() + 'px',
    background: 'white url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');
});


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Page",
    data: JSON.stringify({ parameters: XXXXXXXX }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#ajax-busy').show();
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        $('#ajax-busy').hide();

    },
    error: function() {
        $(document).ajaxError(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('status: ' + ajaxOptions.status + '-' + ajaxOptions.statusText + ' \n' + 'error:\n' + ajaxOptions.responseText);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes styling "disabled" UI like this:

```css
-webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
filter: saturate(0%);
opacity: 0.6;
pointer-events: none;
```

```css
.disabled {
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
  filter: saturate(0%);
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div {
  background: lime;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Enabled:</h2>

<div>
  <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
  <button>I'm a button</button>
</div>

<h2>Disabled:</h2>

<div class="disabled">
  <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
  <button>I'm a button</button>
</div>
```