# How to prevent users' interaction when waiting for ajax's response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to implement some ajax features. For example: when a user clicks a button "get data", jQuery will call an ajax function to fetch some data from the server. This process might take some time, so I added `.ajaxSend` and `.ajaxComplete` functions to show some animation for the waiting process (actually a 'Loading Data' gif inside a div with z-index: 999 to be the top of other divs inside the `<body>`).

During the waiting process (the 'Loading Data'), I would like to prevent users to click other buttons (for example: I have other tabs, buttons below the small 'Loading Data' gif).
The way I achieved this is by:

```
    $("body").ajaxSend(function()
     {
        $(this).append('<div id="loading">Data Loading<\/div>');
        $("div#error").remove();
        $(this).children().not('#loading').css({'opacity':0.22});   
     });
    $("body").ajaxComplete(function()
     {
        $("div#loading").remove();
        $(this).children().not('#loading').css({'opacity':1});
     });
```

However, I don't think changing the opacity is the best way. Unless you make the opacity to 0, users can still click on other buttons/tabs. I don't know how to totally avoid any user interactions during this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an overlay.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Comment: actually, I'm using JqueryUI as well. Yes, I just tried dialog's modal option. It's easy to achieve the block effect I want. However, is there someway to remove the cross-over (close button) on the top-right corner of the dialog?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog

Comment: thanks. I chose this as my answer since I already used JqueryUI so that I don't have to import another plugin only for blockUI effect

Answer (score 6):

I've used jQuery Block UI with good success in the past. Works well with Ajax:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

May be worth using a plugin such as this, rather than handcoding a similar solution...

Comment: well, this plugin works well for this purpose, but I don't want to import too many plugins at this stage. Thanks, anyway. If I can't find a easier solution, I may turn to BlockUI later.

Answer (score 5):

Make visible a div with a z-index above anything else. onsucess, hide it.

For IE6, consider visibility of select inputs

Comment: I wish I could upvote (but I'm out for the next few hours), especially for warning of IE6 and form elements.

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to [CSS/JavaScript Use Div to grey out section of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159914/css-javascript-use-div-to-grey-out-section-of-page).

Answer (score 0):

I use a variant on [Ben Nadel's ajax pipeline](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1392-Handling-AJAX-Errors-With-jQuery.htm).  Essentially he wraps the jQuery $.ajax call with an object that can record outgoing ajax requests.

When an ajax request goes out, you record the request name.  If any more requests attempt to go out with the same name, you don't execute it (optionally providing a message to the user).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get an answer to a similar question and I ended up here. I know it's an old question but I would like to address that an overlay placed over the elements that you want to prevent from interaction, can be easily removed via browser inspector.

It seems to me that the best way to approach this matter is either setting up a global boolean variable for the entire page and just executing actions on the page when ajax isn't running (at least the sensitive actions) or just turning off the asynchronous call for ajax since in fact in this scenario you don't seem to need it (though I know some people will crucify me for saying this).