# load page and iframe simultaneously through javascript

Tags: iframe, load

I had a page(Home.aspx) containing menu on the top and another master page, with same menu on the top.

Now, when i have to move from Home page to master page, i use

```
window.location = 'test.aspx';
```

Now, when i need to move from master to main(Home) page, i need to call a function with a parameter, containing control url, which has to be loaded to the iframe in the Home page.

Can anybody suggest how can i load Home page and iframe within simultaneously using javascript.

Comment: have you tried placing the javascript in the head?

Comment: placing javascript will not solve the issue. actually, i need to first load the Home page and then immediately the iframe, which is already placed in the Home page, in single click, and i need the javascript to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the user interact with the page until the iframe is loaded, you can disable the page with javascript (onLoad of the page `<body onload="disablePage()">`) and enable again when the Iframe is loaded (onLoad of the Iframe `<iframe onload="enablePage()"...` )
Here some post about disable or gray out page: [CSS/JavaScript Use Div to grey out section of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159914/css-javascript-use-div-to-grey-out-section-of-page)